# How can I make something similar to that cool bar on the top of stackoverflow that pops up when you get a new badge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, notifications

When you get a new badge on stackoverflow.com, a bar appears at the top of the screen informing you of your achievement.  It sticks around until the user closes it.

I rather like that system of informing the user about new news related to the site or their account.  It's fairly unintrusive, but still clearly communicates the information.  Even if all users receive a notification this way, it sticks around for each user until they have acknowledged seeing it.

I'm running a system using Ruby on Rails on a PostGres database.  What's the best way to implement a similar system on my setup?

Edit: Just to clarify, I'm interested both in the server side and client side of the setup.

Comment: Start with a `div` tag and some css. Then throw in some ajax and a select and an update query...

Comment: I'm almost sure this is a duplicate... Regardless, I believe the answer is jQuery.

Comment: The answer is *always* jQuery.  How do I pop up a header bar?  jQuery.  How do I design an e-commerce site?  jQuery.  How do I make General Tso Chicken?  *jQuery*.  How was the Large Hadron Collider built?  **jQuery.**

Comment: (P.S. The answer really is jQuery, but it was still a funny comment)

Comment: Is this a server-side or client-side question? Do you want to know how to write this in Rails, how to actually display the element, or both?

Comment: This is both a server-side and client-side question.  Everyone seems to be focusing on the client-side issue, but I'd also like to know what people think is the best way to structure the server-side.

Is jQuery really hands down the way to do this on the client-side?  I've been using the Rails standard Prototype up until now, since I wasn't aware of any compelling need to switch to jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

The effect can be accomplished with jQuery and the slideDown method (http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).  Set an onClick event to make the element slideUp, hide, or hit an AJAX call to let you know that the user got the message and dismissed it.

You could set the contents of the element (I'd go with a div) via an AJAX call, or you could simply populate the div with the appropriate message when generating your page, start the div off as hidden, and then kick off the slideDown method when the page load is complete via a $(document).ready definition (http://think2loud.com/jquery-document-ready-howto/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the jquery popup bubble extension: http://www.farmcode.org/post/2009/04/06/jQuery-popup-bubble-extension.aspx